# Why there are multiple registered cells from getAllCell Api(android)?

Tags: android

I am using the getAllCell api of android.
This is a link.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo
The source code like this.

```
List<CellInfo> allCellInfo = mTelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
int numRegisteredCells = 0;
for (CellInfo cellInfo : allCellInfo) {
 if (cellInfo.isRegistered()) {
  ++numRegisteredCells;
 }
 if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
  verifyLteInfo((CellInfoLte) cellInfo);
 } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
  verifyWcdmaInfo((CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo);
 } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
  verifyGsmInfo((CellInfoGsm) cellInfo);
 }
}
assertTrue("None or too many registered cells : " + numRegisteredCells,
numRegisteredCells > 0 && numRegisteredCells <= 2);
```

We can get the number of registered cell > 0 many times.I don't understand
why there are multiple registered cell.Is this carrier aggregation network?
Somebody can explain for me what the mobile network is when multiple registered cells can occurred?

Appreciate your great help!